# PHP user defined finctions inside for each loops

Tags: php

I'm struggling with something basic here. Can someone explain why I can't call this function and display the code in the browser? The code will output fine when not inside the function.

I'm getting the data from a curl call and using json.I

```
<?php
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
// curl info
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$data = json_decode($response,true);

function person() {
    foreach($data['Appointments'] as $person){
    echo "<span>" . $person['FullName'] . "</span><br>";
    echo "<span>" . $person['DateTimeOfBirth'] . "</span><br>";
    }
 }

 person(); // call the function
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: use `global $data;` inside the function

Comment: Thanks, unsure how I would use that in this instance. I'm struggling to understand the PHP doc hence my post that was closed within seconds

Comment: @AnatoliyR: NO!  Why?  Just pass it in.

Comment: `function person($data) {` then `person($data);`  The first answer to duplicate covers it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - perfect thanks!

Comment: Hey @ultrarun. I have rolled back your edit to your question, because the *answer* should not go into the *question*. The state of a question should be unresolved.